# Where is the displaytag of scheduled reporting?

Tags: java, reporting-services, reporting, displaytag

So I have been making some reports and using displaytag to output these reports in html, csv, excel, pdf, etc.  They are paginated, and take a simple object graph... and output excellent results everytime, with very little code.

However, I need to use displaytag or its equivalent outside of a jsp.  So that a user can schedule a report to run, and that report is stored in a db, or emailed for later viewing.  I have looked at jasper-based reporting solutions, but making a jasper jrxml file is just a nightmare.  I know there are gui tools to help, but I'm content with the simple output of displaytable, so I'm happy to give up that control for ease of implementation.

Really, if I could take the display:table config out of the jsp I would, so please keep that in mind when proposing a solution.

btw, java solutions would be my cup of tea.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to take it out of the JSP? It's doing a perfectly good job there of formatting your data.

You could write some code which makes a web request to your reporting JSP. It then streams the output to disk, or what ever it is you want to do. The simplest way would be to use the [URL](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) and [HttpURLConnection](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) classes to make the request.

Then simply schedule this new code, without having to make any changes to your JSP.

Comment: clearly I do not want to take displaytag out of the jsp, that'd be crazy.  However, I want to use a displaytag-like configuration syntax to emit a report with no dependency on jsp, so that a quartz scheduler can call a domain object.  

I have though about calling into the jsp in the way you mention, however, with the authentication requirements it might be a pain.

Comment: If you need to manage a session, why not use something like HttpUnit to log on and make the necessary requests. It's a pretty simple API.